# Is there a way in HTML patterns to confirm e-mail address

Tags: html

I want to have a form that has an input control for a user's e-mail address, and then I want the other control, one that is the "confirm e-mail address" to check that they are the same.

I have these currently but testing the validation, they only check that each one is a valid address, but dont check they are the same.

Is there a way to do this in HTML5?

My code is this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">E-mail Address:</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="Email" aria-required="true" required/>
```

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="confirmEmail">Confirm E-mail Address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="ConfirmEmailInput" placeholder="ConfirmEmail" onblur="if(this.value!=forms.f.emailInput.value) alert('Nope!')"  aria-required="true" required/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show how you're currently doing the valid address check.

Comment: Not with HTML alone, but you can do it server-side or with Javascript.

Comment: What server side lang are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only with a bit of Javascript

```
<form name="f">
<p><input type="email" name="t1" value=""></p>
<p><input type="email" name="t2" onblur="if(this.value!=forms.f.t1.value) alert('Nope!')"></p>
</form>
```

Or, using your example code with `id` instead of `form` object.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">E-mail Address:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="Email" aria-required="true" required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="confirmEmail">Confirm E-mail Address:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="ConfirmEmailInput" placeholder="ConfirmEmail" 
    onblur="if(this.value!=document.getElementById('emailInput').value) alert('Nope!')"  aria-required="true" required/>
</div>
```

Comment: Just added your js and it didnt work. I added my code to my original question

Comment: I am addressing the second value via the `forms` object: `forms.f.t1.value` where `f` if the name of the parent form and `t1` is the name of the other form field. But you are using `id`s, so that works just as well. I'll add the code to the answer.

Comment: yea sorry i realised that after I posted. even using" forms.form1" didnt work

Comment: That worked! thank you. I have marked your answer :D